# What am I leaving out to have fields editable in the Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have recently added a Personnel table to my models.py and run a syncdb. The database is showing a ccachicago_personnel table as desired, but none of the things left out that I added as I was preparing this question, including restart, have resulted in the admin interface showing the new table. The other models and models.py show up in the admin interface without issue; the new Personnel table does not.

What I have so far is as follows:

In models.py I have:

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    photo_url = models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.DIRNAME +
      '/media/images/')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    linked_in = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    spotlight = models.BooleanField()
```

In my admin.py I asked for Personnel to be registered:

```
from ccachicago.models import Page, Personnel, Redirect
...
admin.site.register(Personnel)
```

In urls.py I have:

```
import ccachicago.admin
...
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

And I've just restarted the server another time, and logged out and in from the admin interface, but nothing has resulted in the new model appearing.

What else can I be doing so that the model appears as desired?

Comment: Do you have 'django.contrib.admin' in the INSTALLED_APPS tupple in the settings.py configuration file?

Comment: Is the `admin.py` file saved? It looks like it *should* work.

Comment: Did you delete old Personnel table?

Comment: Try deleting any .pyc files for your app module. I've had instances where a .pyc won't get re-compiled and I won't see changes. You might also want to set a default value for your boolean fields.

Comment: You're not getting any errors? I assume you just omitted 'from django.contrib import admin' in admin.py?

Comment: @Brandon, please restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it... Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Register the admin class as well (if u do not need any thing fancy, implement it with minimum values... )

```
admin.site.register(Personnel, PersonnelAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/